# Using jquery append method

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I did something like

```
$("#jdoe").append("<h3>Test</h3>");
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jdoe"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It worked as expected (The text Test displays in a h3), I was expecting that if I do a view source in my browser I would see something like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jdoe"><h3>Test</h3></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please correct me if my expectations are wrong

Comment: @freejosh - that's an exact duplicate, voting to close instead !

Comment: @adeneo The comment is automatically added when I cast my initial close vote

Comment: @freejosh - I know, I just agreed with your close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't changed the source of your page, you've changed your DOM.  If you use the developer tools for your preferred browser, you'll see the changes there.

I think you can get developer tools for all browsers by hitting `F12`.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations seem correct...

http://jsfiddle.net/4Uq33/

But to see what it looks like you'll have to use something like Chrome's Inspect Element, not view source.

But I'd suggest doing it more like this:

```
$("#jdoe").append($("<h3>").text("Text"));
```

Comment: Just curious but what is the benefit of doing it this way over the OP's?

Comment: You can end up chaining more jQuery functions onto the end of it if you need to.  For example, `$("#jdoe").append($("<h3>").text("Test").css("color","#f00").on("click",doSomething));`

Comment: Nice. Learn something new everyday. Thanks buddy! :)

Comment: @War10ck - The real benefit is that it uses document.createElement internally, so it actually creates the elements instead of just appending a string of HTML. Creating actual DOM elements is IMO a better approach, but the proper syntax would be `$('<h3 />', {text:'Text'});`

Comment: @adeneo I like that approach the best. Thanks for explanation buddy. :)

Answer (score 0):

your "view source" will be as the same html you get from the server.

Any manipulation with javascript/jquery will not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the console, not the source. In Google Chrome this can be done by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`, from there you can access the other developer tools.